# Trouble in removing background color from div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble in jQuery function I want to remove  background color of array[i].  In this array I have three ids separated by a comma.  I've tried passing array in  `$('#array[i]').css("background-color", "");` but it's not working.

My code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#remove_ss').click(function(){
        var array = $('#selected_show').val().split(",");
        for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            alert(array[i]);
            $('#array[i]').css("background-color", "");
        }        
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('#remove_ss').click(function(){
        var array = $('#selected_show').val().split(",");
        for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    // alert(array[i]);
     var rqiqp = array[i];
     $('#' + array[i]).css("background-color", "");
}
        $('#remososso').css("background-color", "");

    });
})
```

Try this if help full